# Handlebars templates precompiling optimization tips

Tags: optimization, compiler-optimization, handlebars.js, precompile

There is one official optimization [tip](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) on handlebars official website which is related to known helpers.

> handlebars  -f  -k each -k if -k unless

Although I was not been able to find out explicit answer if the precompiling of all templates you have at once is better optimization wise, comparing with partial precompilation and just combing this partial precompiled templates together in one file?

There is obviously would be repeated part like:

```
this.TMPLSNAMESPACE=this.TMPLSNAMESPACE||{},
```

So second approach is already loosing, but apart of this, does handlebars use some sophisticated optimizations for number of templates which are going to be precomiling into one bunch?